# Effect size for an ordinal probit regression

Tags: r, ordinal-data, ordered-probit

I'm trying to simulate an ordinal regression model in order to compute a power analysis in R. Let's assume that I have a 4 level ordinal variable to predict and a dichotomous dummy coded predictor. The model using the `MASS::polr()` function would be:

```r
polr(y ~ x, data = data, method = "probit")
```

In terms of parameters I have 4-1 `thresholds` and the slope associated with the difference in y between the predictor values. Following the book by Agresti ([2010](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470594001)) we can also interpret the slope as the difference in the underlying latent variable in standard deviations terms that for the Probit model would be $\frac{\beta}{\sigma}$ where $\sigma = 1$. So a $\beta= 0.3$ would be a 0.3 standard deviations difference between levels of `x`. This sounds a like a Cohen's d measure, could It be possible to use this approach in order to parametrize a meaningful effect size?